# Using modulo to get random integer in range

Tags: javascript, php

My goal is to have a seeded PRNG that generates the same numbers both in Javascript and in PHP. I found a linear congruential generator that works in both environments, but my problem is that if I use a division to get it in the range I need, Javascript and PHP's different floating precision means the numbers will be slightly different.

I'm not really sure if it would be a problem in my specific case (I don't need numbers higher than 100), but to get around it I tried using the modulo operator. As I expected, since the numbers that the PRNG generates are relatively small, the probability of each number coming out gets smaller as the numbers get higher.

Are there any (possibly simple) algorithms that would work reliably both client and server side?

This is the generator in Javascript that uses the modulo operator to get the integers in range, along with some code that demonstrates that higher numbers come out less frequently

```
function SeededRandom(newSeed) {
    this.seed = newSeed;
    this.Random = function (max) {//max value not included
        this.seed = (this.seed * 20077 + 12345) % 32768;
        return this.seed % max;
    }
}

const MAX_ITER = 1000000;
const MAX_VALUE = 10000;

let random = new SeededRandom(123456);
let array = new Array(MAX_VALUE).fill(0);

for (let iii = 0; iii < MAX_ITER; iii++) {
    array[random.Random(MAX_VALUE)]++;
}

for (let iii = 0; iii < MAX_VALUE; iii++) {
    console.log(iii + ". " + (array[iii] / MAX_ITER));
}
```

Comment: The simplest way i can think of would be to use a PRNG that depends on bitwise operations, which are specified to behave "as if on 32bit" on javascript, which should then be identical to php? E.g. [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) or one of the variants where the operations can be made to behave identical on both languages. Alternatively, i am sure there are ways to make other PRNG behave identical, though maybe more difficult.

Comment: You should show the modulus code you used, and better explain what you mean by "the probability of each number coming out gets smaller as the numbers get higher" because that doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: @Sammitch  the modulus is the standard javascript and php’s % sign. If you run the code I provided (which calculates the probability of each number coming out) you’ll see what I mean.

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks I’ll give it a shot :)

Comment: Yes. If your desired range does not evenly divide the range of the output of your PRNG you're going to have this happen. That's why you should use a better PRNG that can output a full 32 or 64 bit integer that relegates that problem to a very small margin of error.

Comment: If you want the same numbers at the same time, doesn't that really make the whole point of being random useless? Is any given number allowed to appear more than once?